# The webpage view on the phone is too large until the first click

Tags: html, css, mobile, sass, viewport

I have a question and actually a small problem.This is my first created website after small course. When I access the page on mobile, until I made first click (anywhere) the viewport looks like a bit stretched. If I click anywhere, everything returns to normal. The problem annoying enough, but invisible in devtools( on phone in devtools everything is ok)

Have you ever seen something like this?
Here is link to my website: https://dleksy.github.io/CV-DanielL/

Tried to reproduce it somehow in devtools, tried on different phones (the same result), tried to change the height: vh I would like to have the view everytime the same, with every visit.

Comment: Is there maybe a transform on header? From the video it looks like the header has  gone to "fixed" position or something and under the header.

Comment: After few days it was fixed without any actions from my side

Answer (score 0):

Fixed without any action from my side. After some days started work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).